# Excluding certain columns from a database query based on criteria in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The situation:

A `profile` table (about 30+ columns) has values saved by the user. Another table has same columns specifying the access level for each row (privacy - e.g. `Friend`, `Public` etc.) .

When a user wishes to view the profile of a certain user, the query should check which columns can be viewed by the inquiring user based on his/her relation with the person .

Kindly suggest an efficient approach for performing this task efficiently ..

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: [What have **YOU** tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) - we're glad to help if you're stuck on specific issues - we're not just going to design and write your code for you

Comment: The only idea can think of is to check for each field and write a Dynamic query but that theoretically sounds too inefficient .. Only intention is to gain some guide for any efficient approach (built-in method) for excluding columns on run-time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create separate Views for each privacy type. Each View should have only columns allowed to view according privacy. Then use appropriate View for current privacy.

Comment: thank you for the Answer.. Have implemented privacy at Server side..